# Devart Oracle provider direct mode issues with parametrized queries

Tags: devart, prepared-statement

I'm having some bizarre issues with parametrized queries in direct mode.

Basically if I perform an insert on a table that already contains a unique row I get an insert exception which is expected. After the insert exception I use this same connection to grab the info for which data is already locked down to report the user (I know the connection is still good at this point). This connection is then closed and returned to the pool all of this is fine up to this point as expected.

At a later point in time when this connection is grabbed back from the pool I try to perform a simple update parametrized query and I get the following exception: ORA-01008: not all variables bound. This would make sense to get if all variables were not bound however looking at the OracleParameter collection I can clearly see that all parameters exist and that their values are correct. Not to mention this query gets run multiple times before this connection is grabbed from the pool for other connections in the pool since it's a general update table that gets updated for each client request. Furthermore all of this code works fine with direct mode turned off using the oracle client (exact same code and query execution as in direct mode).

Basically it seems that for some reason in direct mode when the insert is performed and fails and the connection gets closed and placed back into the pool that the connection becomes corrupt and fails when used again with parametrized queries.

I would produce a simple sample except the only problem is that this issue is not reliably reproducible in a simple case.

Info:

- This is a client server app. Issue occurs even with a single client.
- Connection is created and grabbed from the pool for each client request and closed after execution of the request.
- Each connection is used within a single thread (not across multiple threads)
- Using the latest Devart.Data.Oracle 5.35.54 and Devart.Data 5.0.16 and i've also tried with the previous version with the same results.

If any one has come across this or has any ideas your help will be greatly appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have replied you [here](http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=16604) at our forum.